# Why won't my Kendo grid bind to my OData source with the default XML format?

Tags: odata, kendo-ui

I took the example code from the Kendo UI demos at http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/remote-data.html, binding to the remote data source that they show. This worked fine.

I removed the schema bits and the column list from the Kendo examples and tried again. Now all the columns in the data source are displayed in the grid and all is still fine.

I then changed to URI for the oData source from the demo one to one on my own machine at "http://localhost:61539/SQLOData.svc/Companies". This is a WCF data service created using the steps in the Microsoft example for oData linked to SQL Server (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_buildingappandservicesusingodatavs2010_topic3.aspx).

When I now view my grid there's no data in it. How can this be?

My oData service seems to be working. When I browse to `http://localhost:61539/SQLOData.svc/Companies` I see the data as XML.

Comment: Are you sure that your service gets hit? Use Fiddler to make sure your service is getting called -- you can also use Fiddler to check if there are any errors..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I needed to get hold of the DataServiceJSONP addin and include the appropriate attribue in my service.